# How to use an angularJs filter on items label within ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Given a select list loaded with product options, I want the label to be in the format of option name and then price in parenthesis.  So for example:  "Product Option B ($1,432.12)".  My option object has the properties "name" and "price".  Price is numeric, I want it formatted with the currency filter.  How would I do this?  I'm thinking maybe a custom filter that takes a string and numeric value.  Just not sure how I would be able to apply the filter within ng-options.

The following code just displays the name (not price):

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="selectedOption"
        ng-options="option.name for option in category.options"></select>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just decorate your model in the controller/directive with something like a displayName attribute?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<select class="form-control"
    ng-model="selectedOption"
    ng-options="option.name + ' (' + (option.price | currency:'USD$') + ')' for option in options">
</select>
```

This will render a drop-down with items in this form: `Item A (USD$14.00)`

http://jsfiddle.net/6MYc3/

Comment: This is perfect but I have one problem. I have options which I want to show like this `code - desc`. But one of my options is `code=""`, `desc=""` and in the result I get `" - "` but I want just to be blank as `""`. How can I achieve this please?

Comment: oh I see `option.code as option.code==='' ? '' : (option.code + ' - ' + option.desc) for option in options`